# How to get resolution of "closed" from optilude when getting Jira stats

Tags: jira

Wondering if anyone can help me with this.

I'm trying to run Optilude (https://github.com/optilude/jira-cycle-extract) in the Windows10 command line.

I have installed everything, set up the yaml file as instructed, and have it running.

Every time I run it however, I get the following error:

```
r.status_code, error, r.url, request=request, response=r, **kwargs) jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400 url: https://livesport.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project+%3D+VELCRO+AND+issueType+IN+%28%22Story%22%2C+%22Task%22%2C+%22Bug%22%29+AND+%28resolution+IS+EMPTY+OR+resolution+IN+%28%22Done%22%2C+%22Closed%22%29%29+ORDER+BY+updatedDate+DESC&validateQuery=True&startAt=0&expand=changelog
        text: The value 'Closed' does not exist for the field 'resolution'.
```

This is the yaml file snippet, which asks for the resolutions:
[image: yaml file snippet]

And this is my Jira board, with resolution set to both Closed and Done.
[image: Jira board settings]

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why it's not picking up the resolution for "Closed"? Is there some other way I need to set this, or write in the yaml file?

If I remove the "Closed" from the yaml file, it runs happily past that error point (and onto the next unrelated error - but that's another issue..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you have "Closed" resolution at this JIRA setup? If issue has a resolution it mean that it is closed.

Comment: Um..  yes.  I have added a screenshot to the post, with the resolution of "Closed" in the Done column.  Stories are showing "closed" just fine.  So the workflow is working.

Comment: On your screenshot is more like statuses. Could you provide list of resolutions, available into your Jira instance? Admin permission requared for this.

Comment: Ah! You mean the list you get under Admin -> Issues -> Resolutions
You are correct!  It doesn't exist there. I hadn't even seen that screen hiding in there. 
Many thanks